# Better way to register ItemBlock than what I have here?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I am trying to get an ItemBlock to register alongside my Block when it gets registered. I have come up with this so far. Is there a better way to be doing this?  I'm not really happy with the `itemBlock.setRegistryName` part inside `registerBlock()` !

```
public class ModBlocks {

    public static Block tinBlock;

    public static void init(){
        tinBlock = new BlockTinBlock("tin_block", "tin_block");
    }

    public static void register(){
        registerBlock(tinBlock);
    }

    public static void registerRenders(){
        registerRender(tinBlock);
    }

    public static void registerBlock(Block block){
        GameRegistry.register(block);
        ItemBlock itemBlock = new ItemBlock(block);
        itemBlock.setRegistryName(Reference.MODID, block.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
        GameRegistry.register(itemBlock);
    }

    public static void registerRender(Block block){
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(Item.getItemFromBlock(block), 0, new ModelResourceLocation(new ResourceLocation(Reference.MODID, block.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5)), "inventory"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what minecraft version are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stumbled across a link that was posted to me on the `MinecraftForge` forums 2 days ago. This method of registering items and blocks is up-to-date, and uses the `RegistryEvents`! Have a look, and consider switching over!

[[MinecraftForge] 1.11.2 - Is using RegistryEvent this way ok?](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/49497-1112-is-using-registryevent-this-way-ok/#comment-249433)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pretty much it, but for the registration of Blocks, Items and Models etc. you should use the corresponding event:
To do this you will need an Event listener listening for the Event.
An event listener is a function that takes the Event as the parameter and is Annotated `@SubscribeEvent`  they can either be located in your `@Mod` class
or in classes Annotated  `@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = "yourmodid")`

To register Blocks, Items and Models in a separate class you would write something like this:

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = "yourmodid")
public class Registration{
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerBlocks(RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
        IForgeRegistry registry = event.getRegistry();
        //register blocks here using registry
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerItems(RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
        //register items here like we did with the blocks
    }

    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void initModels(ModelRegistryEvent event) {
        //register models here
    }
}
```

More information on this subject can be found in the official Minecraft Forge Documentation that can be found [here](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/registries/).

Comment: Hey BDoubleB97,
I have actually found an amazing way to register item in a post on Minecraft Forge that uses these events, but in a much more orderly fashion. Thanks for the help, but I'm going to post that link as the correct answer!